# Chart is not visible in Parameter Variation Experiment page in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I created the parameter variation experiment to observe the changes in model outcome by changing specific parameter "ContactRateInfectious" values. **Once I set the parameter values and Create default UI, no chart appeared**. The image of my experiment page is given below.

[image]

I was expecting to see a chart that looked like this:

[image]

Let me know how can I achieve this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You open the AnyLogic example models
2. You search for "Parameter Variation"
3. You open the first model you find (hint: it is called "Bass diffusion")
4. You copy the chart over
5. You figure out how they fill the chart from the model runs (see the Param-Var experiment properties in the example model)
6. You adapt it to your model

Done :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an example model with a chart on the parameter variation experiment page, but I do have an image of the chart that I showed in my question description.

Comment: steps adjusted ;)

Comment: (Always worth searching all example models for your problems first, they have a ton of solutions at your fingertips)